# "Somee" label text not showing

Tags: asp.net

Got a Somee account and used the following code copied from internet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to website Label Text "Label" does not show. Any clues as to why not?

Comment: Since you are just trying to show off the value of a label, means nothing special, why won't you just create a new Web Application solution using Visual Studio?

Comment: I have a Web Application using Visual Studio but it has a problem with Label Text not showing when loaded into Somee so I am using this bit of code to find out what the problem is.

Comment: I assume that Somee is a hosting provider right? Have you checked their default ASP.NET settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as your suits.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1"
           Text="Label:"
           AssociatedControlID="TextBox"
           runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server" />
</asp:Label>
```